# A way to determine ID of form during POST method

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if it was in any way possible to be able to determine the ID of the form that was posted on PHP?

```
<form id="ES1A" action="enroll.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next Step</button>
</form>
```

In the enroll.php

```
if(isset($_POST['ES1A']))
{
  //Code after checking that the form that was submitted indeed has the ID of ES1A
}
```

P.S: I'm not too sure on how i would do this on PHP. Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you not just add a hidden input and place the form ID into that value?

Comment: Just use a hidden input-field with the form-id as value, There is no better way, i believe.

Comment: No (not without a manual workaround). _BUT_ this sounds like an XY Problem. Why do you wanna do this?

Comment: @jeff well i wanted to have multiple forms that redirect to that same .php file.. what do you mean by "XY Problem"

Blinkydamo good idea.. but isnt it more efficient if there was a way to do that without adding hidden forms?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post does not use the ID of the element, rather the name, so instead of your current form, you could use;

```
<form name="ES1A" action="enroll.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <input name="formid" value="ES1A" /><!-- This holds your form id so you can use this -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next Step</button>
</form>
```

And in the PHP;

```
if (isset($_POST['ES1A']) // Unsure if form itself will be posted with the submit
{
    // This is set as it uses the name of the element
    $formid = $_POST['formid']; // Get the ID of the form from the element passed in
}
```

Comment: I hardly believe that the name of the form will not be sent by submitting. correctme if i'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not too sure either, it's not impossible, but this is just to use the OP's example :)

Comment: Thanks for the input.. :) going to use it for now.. but i'm really looking for that method.. (if its even possible lol)

Comment: @DeathKing - if this resolves the issue, please consider clicking that tick so users know you have found a solution, else people won't know :)

Answer (score 0):

If form's name attribute does not work you can always set name for button:

```
<button name="ES1A" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next Step</button>
```

Or:

```
<input name="ES1A" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next Step">
```

PHP part should be the same as you already have:

```
if(isset($_POST['ES1A']))
{
  //Code after checking that the form that was submitted indeed has the ID of ES1A
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "PHP part should be the same"? provide an example.

Comment: The same as in the OP's example

Answer (score 0):

an alternative is to use hidden input

```
 <input name="ES1A" value="formid" type="hidden" />
```